# Reactjs update background image of Body dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dynamic, background-image

I want to change background image applied to the Body dynamically. I am using unsplash api to get random photos. The css applied to the Body tag looks like below:
index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506501139174-099022df5260?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEzNjgxNH0");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The following code from the functional component updates the backgroundImage in the state. I want to apply that dynamic url from the state to the css applied on the Body tag. Please find the code below:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Input, Button, Divider, Typography } from "antd";
import axios from "axios";
import { GlobalContext } from "../../contexts/GlobalState";
const { Title } = Typography;

export const SearchBox = () => {
  const [location, updateLocation] = useState("");
  const { updateBackground } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const onCityChange = (e) => {
    updateLocation(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSearch = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=${location}&client_id=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const url = `"url('${response.data.results[5].urls.full}')"`;
        updateBackground(url);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col span={24} style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
          <Title level={4}>Weather App</Title>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col
          span={24}
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Input
            size="large"
            placeholder="City Name"
            onChange={(e) => onCityChange(e)}
          />
          <Button
            size="large"
            type="primary"
            onClick={onSearch}
            style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Divider plain></Divider>
    </>
  );
};
```

How do I update background image of the Body dynamically ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily with styled-components. You can use this:

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    background: ${props => (props.something ? url(imageone) : url(imagetwo))};
  }
`
```

that way you can pass a prop in and then render something different based off that. I do this to render a different background image for my app

the docs are here: https://styled-components.com/docs/api

let me know if you need any more details